# How to include Jquery in the background script (not the content script) for my Firefox Jetpack Addon?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on porting a Chrome extension over to Firefox. In the Chrome extension, the background script includes JQuery, which is used for AJAX throughout the background scripts.

With the Firefox Jetpack SDK, it looks like i can do:

```
require("modulename")
```

but this only works if modulename is a firefox extension module, including the code:

```
exports.someVar = someLocalVar
```

in order to make the module functionality available elsewhere. Obviously JQuery isn't set up as a module like this, so there's no way to require it.

Is there some way to include JQuery in my lib/main.js file in the background of my Firefox addon, such that I get access to JQuery in my main() function?

Comment: What do you want with jQuery in `main.js`? jQuery is meant to access DOM, `main.js` has no access to DOM however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting this, I've recognized that it's a somewhat futile endeavor. As Wladimir Palant points out in the comments, JQuery is meant to access the DOM. Since the main.js file has no window or document objects, this functionality is entirely useless.

I had intended to use JQuery for AJAX, which works correctly in Chrome backgrounds scripts, but Firefox addons have no XMLHttpRequest object, so JQuery is pretty useless here as well. The correct solution is to rewrite my code using the firefox Request() API instead.

If you would like to include JQuery in CommonJS applications, I found this project, which puts JQuery into a module, assuming you have window, document, and XMLHttpRequest defined: https://github.com/jakobmattsson/commonjs-jquery

Comment: I'll also add that if you need the DELETE HTTP method (as I did), which the Request API doesn't support, you can use the lower-level xhr API. Just use require('xhr').XMLHttpRequest in the same way you'd use XMLHttpRequest in Firefox.

Comment: I need to "inject" both my own script (is that a "content" script?) as well as jquery into the current web page so I can interact with them using my addon's script.  This github script you refer to, is that the way?

Comment: Hi BGM, no this answer is referring to the background script. You'll want to use the tab.attach method to run scripts on a page. See http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2011/09/01/add-on-sdk-faq-content-script-access/